# problem with firebase google login in signed app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am logging in with google in my application, but when I made a signed apk and uploaded it to my phone while it was working properly on the virtual device, I couldn't log in with google. I had installed it on my phone before and it was working fine.

Also, after installing the apk on the phone, when I want to use my own phone in android studio, I get the error that the signatures are different, I would appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond using @AlexMamo